# How do you spread out a specific part of the x-axis in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(tw = rep(c(1:30), each = 3),
                 name = rep(c("spec1", "spec2", "spec3"), each = 1),
                 id = rep(c(1:10), each = 90),
                 value = sample(x = 0:100, size = 900, replace = TRUE))
```

Where tw (time window) represents units of time, but they are not evenly spaced. From tw 1:25 is every 500 years, whereas from tw 26 - 30 is every ~ 1500 years.

At the moment I'm plotting it like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=df, aes(x=tw, y=value, group=interaction(id, name), colour=name),  alpha = .15) +
  scale_x_reverse(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 15)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#ffa644", "#30460a", "#E64056")) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 25, ) +
  ylab("Percentage (%)") + 
  xlab("Time") +
  labs(colour = "Taxa")  +
  theme_bw()
```

I'd like tws 26:30 (before the intercept line) to be spaced further apart than 1:25 along the x axis, to represent the longer time gap. I've tried to draw an example below.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8wX6.png)

I tried:

```
scale_x_reverse(breaks = c(29, 27, 25:1))
```

but this didn't have the effect of spreading the graph, it just skipped out numbering tws 28 and 26.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either set up a transform for the axis, or you can do it manually by manipulating your data and axis. I'll demonstrate the latter approach here.

Essentially, if `tw` is larger than 25, then subtract 25 from `tw`, multiply by 3 and add 25 back on. Do the same when you are creating the axis breaks. However, when you are creating the axis *labels*, reverse this process. If the label is going to be higher than 25, subtract 25, divide by 3 and add 25 back on to the displayed value.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = df, alpha = 0.15,
            aes(x = ifelse(tw > 25, 25 + (tw - 25) * 3, tw), y = value,
                group = interaction(id, name), col = name)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#ffa644", "#30460a", "#E64056")) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 25, ) +
  ylab("Percentage (%)") + 
  scale_x_reverse(labels = ~ifelse(.x > 25, (.x - 25)/3 + 25, .x),
                  name = "Time", breaks = c(2*(0:12)-1, (25:30 - 25)*3 + 25)) +
  labs(colour = "Taxa")  +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]